# BibTex file from Zotero does not match my style

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, zotero, mdpi

I exported my references from Zotero in BibTex format and uploaded the `.bib` file into my project in Overleaf. My webpage references in Zotero `.bib` output are categorized as `@misc`. However, my style (`mdpi.bst` file) uses `@www` for webpages. When I manually change it to `@www` I can't cite it in the main text. I can still use `@misc`, but I am afraid it is not right.

Should I export from Zotero differently?

Comment: did you try to edit the .bib file before uploading it to overleaf?

Comment: Hi - if you are still having trouble with using this, please get in touch with Overleaf support  (I'm on the support team.), and they may be able to offer some suggestions: support@overleaf.com.